# Loop with counter

Tags: python, html, pug, pyjade

I'm trying to do the age-old gallery loop counter using jade (I'm a newb). I'm using twitter bootstrap so I need to put the images into divs with col-md-3 as a class and as a child of a div with row". So, ideally it looks like this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">image goes here</div>
    <div class="col-md-3">image goes here</div>
    <div class="col-md-3">image goes here</div>
    <div class="col-md-3">image goes here</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">image goes here</div>
    <div class="col-md-3">image goes here</div>
    <div class="col-md-3">image goes here</div>
    <div class="col-md-3">image goes here</div>
</div>
```

Where I'm stuck is how to initialize a new row since indentation matters in jade. Below is what I'm starting with, how do I proceed?

```
div.row
    each product, index in collection.products
        div.col-md-3: img
```

I would assume you'd use something like:

```
if index % 3
    div.row
```

...but it doesn't feel quite right...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it going a different direction. I created a [context_processor](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/templating/#context-processors) at the top of my views.py file and that made it available to my template as a function.

views.py

```
@app.context_processor
def utility_processor():
    def subdivide_list(list_to_group, group_size):
        return [list_to_group[i:i+group_size] for i  in range(0, len(list_to_group), group_size)]
return dict(subdivide_list=subdivide_list)
```

gallery.jade

```
div.col-md-9
    for product_row in subdivide_list(all_products, 4)
        div.row
            for product in product_row
                img(src="{{ url_for('static', filename='uploads/images/products/'+product.image.name_thumb) }}")
```